# Unable to use autohide launcher in 12.10

Tags: launcher, 12.10

I upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10. Everything went well but the launcher *does not show* when I move the mouse cursor on it.

My computer is HP Pavillion p6582l, Core i5, 4GB of RAM, Nvidia GeForce GF315 3D graphic card.

Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Solved adding

```
Option     "ConstrainCursor" "no"
```

to Section "Device" of xorg.conf (if xorg.conf is not present, create it with "nvidia settings") as described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12279749&postcount=12).

Comment: Where to find xorg.conf ? Add that into your answer, thanks.

Comment: /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Answer (score 2):

Try the easiest way first.

Go to **System Settings → Appearance** or just press the **super** key (windows key) and type "appearance".

In the window that opens, go to **Behavior** tab and switch **Auto-hide the Launcher** to **ON** and **Reveal Location** to **Left Side** as shown below. If this doesn't work, do let me know.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for editing it @msPeachy. I'm sorry, I'm new at AU. How did you add the 'arrow'?

Comment: You're welcome. Press Ctrl+Shift+U then add 2192 it would look like (u2192) with an underline but once you press space it till turn into an arrow.

Comment: Any link to more such shortcuts?

Answer (score -1):

go to compiz settings manager if not installed do it via synaptic or `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`. Run it and search for  **ubuntu unity plugin** check if itis enabled [image]

Find **experimental** title.

Then change value in **launcher reveal preassure**

.Also you can run `unity --replace` or  `setsid unity` in terminal to restart it.
See if it works. ps 
how to reset unity if something went wrong 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwFG9XpdYEg