# Launcher does not pop in - is out permanently

Tags: 11.10, 12.10, boot

I have upgraded my ubuntu to 12.10 and the launcher is out permanently. It does not pop in thus my screen is smaller and very uncomfortable. Is there any setting i can change to make it pop in and out again? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want your launcher to dodge windows on maximize:
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/how-to-get-unity-launcher-window-dodge.html  - this link explains how.

For plain ol' hiding all the time, the question was answered, see here for instructions: 
[Unable to use autohide launcher in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204920/unable-to-use-autohide-launcher-in-12-10)

Enjoy your Ubuntu! :D